# Cannot install Visual Studio 2013 update 5 (RTM); Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to install VS2013 update 5 but it will not install as it says it is blocked and I must "uninstall the older version of Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Multi Device Hybrid Apps) through Control Panel...".

I have uninstalled this as requested (though the new version - 14.0.50619.1 - that installs with VS2015 is still installed) but it still will not let me install and keeps repeating the message.

From Help/About...

> Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00081
>
> Installed Version: Premium
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft
>   LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013
>
> Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564
>   Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013
>
> Visual Basic 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2013
>
> Visual C# 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft Visual C# 2013
>
> Visual C++ 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft Visual C++ 2013
>
> Visual F# 2013   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft Visual F# 2013
>
> Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker
>   06191-004-0454001-02564 Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis
>   Spell Checker
>
> Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system ©
>   1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third
>   Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version
>   licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   06191-004-0454001-02564 Windows Phone
>   SDK 8.0 - ENU
>
> .NET Reflector Visual Studio Extension   8.5.0.179 Integrates .NET
>   Reflector into Visual Studio to allow you to seamlessly debug into
>   third-party code and assemblies, even if you don't have the source
>   code for them.
>
> Visit www.reflector.net for more information.
>
> Copyright (c) 2009-2012 Red Gate Software Inc.
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0 Application
>   Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   12.4.60425.0 Microsoft Web Developer Tools
>   contains the following components: Support for creating and opening
>   ASP.NET web projects Browser Link: A communication channel between
>   Visual Studio and browsers Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and
>   JavaScript Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
>   Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
>   Server Explorer extensions for Microsoft Azure Web Apps Web
>   publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting
>   providers, on-premises servers, or Microsoft Azure
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.21010.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.5 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Devart dotConnect for Oracle   8.4.447.0 Devart dotConnect for Oracle
>   Copyright 2002 - 2015 Devart. All rights reserved. Web:
>   www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle Support: support@devart.com
>
> Devart Entity Developer   5.7.644.0 Devart Entity Developer Copyright
>   © 2008-2015 Devart. All rights reserved. Web:
>   www.devart.com/entitydeveloper  Support: support@devart.com
>
> File Nesting   2.1.2 Automatically nest files based on file name and
>   enables developers to nest and unnest any file manually
>
> Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone    Microsoft Advertising
>   SDK for Windows Phone Build
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.2200.0 Language service
>   for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.2200.0 An
>   integrated development environment for HDInsight application
>   development.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.3 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.6 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2013 - v2.6.30508.1601
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.4 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2013 - v2.4.20730.1601
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.7 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2013 - v2.7.30713.1601
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.5 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2013 - v2.5.21104.1601
>
> Multilingual App Toolkit   3.1.1250.0 Multilingual App Toolkit helps
>   you localize your Windows Store app by providing file management,
>   pseudo and machine translation, translation editor, and build
>   integration. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=245767
>
> NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50926.663 NuGet Package Manager in Visual
>   Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit
>   http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   12.0.31105
>   Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU
>
> Open Command Line   1.6 Opens a command line at the root of the
>   project. Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc.
>
> Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio   12.1.0.2.0 Oracle Developer
>   Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2014
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services    Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
>   Designer  Version 12.0.2000.8
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.50512.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
>   Services Designer Version 12.0.2344.23
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services    Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
>   Services Designers  Version 12.0.2344.23
>
> Web Essentials 2013   2.6.0.0 Adds many useful features to Visual
>   Studio for web developers.
>
> Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration   1.0 This package integrates the
>   tools for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK into the menus and controls of
>   Visual Studio.
>
> Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0 This package contains the necessary
>   Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Has anybody else seen this and is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Also just noticed that, according to Programs and Features, I now have VS2013 Premium with Update 3 installed though Help/About tells me Update 4. Azure tools 2.7 did not fully install because they said update 4 required!

Comment: I have now raised this on Microsoft Connect; I will update with any response I receive. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1572538/cannot-install-visual-studio-2013-update-5-rtm-tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp-false-positive

Comment: I have the same problem.  I even tried uninstalling the VS 2015 Cordova tools just to be safe, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Can you try this -

Open RegEdit, find this key:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\JavaScriptLanguageService
Delete the MDD-specific value:  “ReferenceGroups_MDD”.
Do not delete the “ReferenceGroups” value, or you may mess up your JSLS intelli-sense for non-MDD scenarios.

Deleting that ReferenceGroups_MDD value under the JSLS key should unblock the installation of any installers that are blocking because they (incorrectly) think that you still have the VS2013 Tools for Apache Cordova installed.

**Note**: If you upgrade to Update5, you will lose the ability to work with MDD projects until we release the next version of our tools that work on top of update5. We are in process of validating our next release for Update5 and will release it soon.

Comment: You sir are an absolute star. I removed the key as you described and VS2013 Update 5 is now installed. Thank you.

Comment: Just one more thing; going out on a limb here but from the avatar and the wording of your suggestions, would I be correct to assume that you are a part of the VS/MDA team? If so, keep up the good work and don't worry that I cannot use it with VS2013 any more as I already have VS2015 installed (complete with Tools for Apache Cordova).

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes, I am a part of the VS/MDA team as a Program manager. I wlil let the team know of your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that the uninstall of our tools (for Apache Cordova) is not working for you.

The command to uninstall a previous version of the tools has 2 different GUIDS in it.

```
"%ProgramData%\Package Cache\{f2f851cc-42a1-41f2-a2cd-a0e4627a60cb}\vs2013mda_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force/burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
```

The first is the GUID of the Cordova package that you have installed on your machine that you want to uninstall.  You can find the correct GUID to use by searching under %ProgramData%\Package Cache for vs2013mda_0.1.exe and find the GUID of the folder where it resides.  Substitute the GUID you find on your machine for the first GUID in the command line script.

The second GUID in the command is the GUID of the package that is blocking the uninstall.  There are a number of packages that will block the uninstall, and we have included a command for all of them but perhaps not with the right combination of MDD GUID that you have on your machine.

Here is a guide to which GUID you should use in the 2nd part of the command:

If you have VS 2013 Update 4 installed on your machine:
{53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763}

If you have VS 2013 Update 5 CTP1 installed on your machine:
{ee836379-0143-481a-97c9-d577d049e22a}

If you have VS 2013 Update 5 CTP2 installed on your machine:
{cf552a8c-484b-4e33-afe7-c81dfadb0cfc}

If none of these work for you still, you can find the correct GUID to use by looking in the uninstall log for the MDD tools.  When you attempt to uninstall MDD tools via Add Remove Programs, it will create a log file in %Temp% called dd_mda_tools_YYYYMMDDNNNN.log.  In that uninstall log there will be a line that looks something like this:
Detected related bundle: {53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763}, type: Dependent. 
Chances are the GUID for the related bundle in your file will be different from the ones we have covered in the pre-constructed commands.  You can substitute the dependent GUID that you find in your uninstall log for the GUID in the 2nd part of the command.

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer, unfortunately it has not helped; I have searched %ProgramData%\Package Cache\ and there are no files starting with vs2013 other than update 4.

Comment: I should probably add: the uninstaller ran without apparent error. Control Panel no longer shows the extension installed, it is only when I try and install update 5 that the problem occurs as it is telling me that the extension is still installed when it is not. I suspect that something has been left-over after the uninstall and update 5 is finding this and using it to determine that the extension is still installed.

Comment: I have also tried reinstalling CTP 3.1; it too is blocked claiming that a previous version is already installed...