# Uninstalled VS Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 but Visual Studio 2013 update5 install still blocked

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013

[image: vs2013.5 install]

I successfully uninstalled VS Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 from programs and features, as requested by the vs2013.5 installer. However the message is not going away.

I never installed Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio 2013 CTP2.0 or earlier, or Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0, so there should not be anything previous to 3.1 getting in the way.

vs2013 update5 log excerpt for PackageId vsupdate_kb2829760 (cordova tools)

```
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:27]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vsupdate_kb2829760
[1624:1608][2015-07-22T09:04:27]i301: Applying execute package: vsupdate_kb2829760, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2E67C8D07447FDB3222D9F602AFAFAD3E60DC1CB\packages\vsupdate_kb2829760\vsupdate_kb2829760.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2E67C8D07447FDB3222D9F602AFAFAD3E60DC1CB\packages\vsupdate_kb2829760\vsupdate_kb2829760.exe" /q /norestart /DisableSystemRestore /chainingpackage vs_professional_enu_slip   /log "C:\Users\Edu\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_professional_20150722085711_063_vsupdate_kb2829760.log" /OriginalSource "C:\Users\Edu\Downloads\vs_professional.exe" /OriginalDisplayMode "Full" -burn.ancestors={ddf731da-94ef-4dd0-98f9-6eb3656bebf7}'
[1624:1608][2015-07-22T09:04:43]e000: Error 0x80044000: Process returned error: 0x80044000
[1624:1608][2015-07-22T09:04:43]e000: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:43]e000: Error 0x80044000: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:43]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vsupdate_kb2829760 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 4485120  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1335296
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:43]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80044000 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:43]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147205120 (0x80044000), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vsupdate_kb2829760
[0C5C:15C0][2015-07-22T09:04:43]w350: Applied non-vital package: vsupdate_kb2829760, encountered error: 0x80044000. Continuing...
```

Not sure how to proceed next...

Comment: I would suggest jumping abord the vs 2015 train. This is just an opinion after struggling a lot with cordova and vs 2013. Much better integration in 2015.

Comment: @Dave Appreciated, however I still would like to install vs2013 update 5

Comment: There is a similar question and Subhag has provided some steps to troubleshoot the issue. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526378/cannot-install-visual-studio-2013-update-5-rtm-tools-for-apache-cordova

Comment: @Alan Yao - yep that's the exact issue I have run into, looks like Microsoft are looking into it

Comment: there is now a working solution @ the link above by Alan Yao

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't uninstall Cordova CPT 3.1. Please check your control -> Programs to confirm it exist or not. If Cordova CPT 3.1 still exist, you can remove it by following below steps:

1.Open Visual Studio 2013 > Tools > Extensions > under All installed extension, search for “Cordova” and uninstall it. And close the Visual Studio.

2.Start Command Prompt and find vs2013mda_0.3.exe in C:\Program Data folder:

```
CD "%ProgramData%\Package Cache"
dir /s vs2013*.*
```

3.Above command will normally list 2 items found with each file on different GUID folders, one containing VS2013.4.exe and the other vs2013mda_0.3.exe. To start removing process, use the following command from your current Command Prompt path:

```
[GUID]\vs2013mda_0.1.exe /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
```

4.Check your control panel, Cordova CPT 3.1 should remove from your program. Restart your computer.